# Firebase UI auth and my own server side back end db

Tags: web-services, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am a mobile app developer and happened to come across firebaseUI.
I am trying to build an application which communicates with a webservice which provide some features.
As a starting point to create a webservice (java webservice) I was trying to use FirebaseUI for authentication.

When I started doing a sample project in firebase, I could see that the user data get saved in the Firebase's real time db.
Is there any way to plug in our webservice code to interact with our own db instead of firebase db ?
If there is a way, what extra things I have to do from my side to create a complete login-sign up- forgot password flow(or what features provided by firebse UI I have to rewrite)?

Another related question: If I adopt this firebase UI - webserver flow, can I continue using the free firebase plan as I am not using the real time database or storage now?

Comment: FirebaseUI is an open-source library. By forking the code, you can make it do pretty much whatever you want against whatever back-end services you want.

Comment: I would like to add that Firebase Auth has its own user database and is not part of real time database. You can use Firebase Auth on its own without using real time database service or any other Firebase service and instead use your own web service/daatbase. Firebase Auth also provides CLI SDK to download these users if you need to.

Comment: @bojeil Thanks for the help! So the limitations that apply to realtime database (price quota) is not applicable at all when I use free trial of Firebase Auth? And can I use it as long as Google keeps it as free without paying anything and without any cap (number of users accessing/ database size)?

Comment: Firebase auth is completely free, except if you are using phone auth. You have 10,000 free SMS verifications per month.  For more details, check https://firebase.google.com/pricing/